# Twitter Feeds on the footer

Tags: html, css, twitter

I have always used twitter widget part but I am wondering how can I put the twitter feed just like this site on its footer?

http://www.oliverwyman.com/index.html

Twitter widget code I used

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE">Tweets </a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example doesn't appear to have a working twitter feed at the minute, but any sort of custom usage of the twitter information now requires use of OAuth authentication. If you visit the twitter API documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs then you will be able to find out more information.

Additionally, using javascript with OAuth is "strongly discouraged" according to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries.